# How to skip empty rows in vba macro

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing vba macro which copy / pastes the `O, P, Q, R` column values to a table in another worksheet. The problem is that it is also pasting the blank values resulting in empty rows in the table. I only want the rows which have some value to be pasted into the table (skip the blank rows). Then, after the row values are pasted into the table, the cells in the original sheet get blank. Below is the code and the image of the worksheet.

```vb
Sub CopyCols()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim LastRow As Long, LastRowDes As Long, header As Range, foundHeader As Range, foundHeader2 As Range, foundHeader3 As Range, foundHeader4 As Range, foundHeader5 As Range, foundHeader6 As Range, foundHeader7 As Range, foundHeader8 As Range, foundHeader9 As Range, foundHeader10 As Range, lCol As Long, srcWS As Worksheet, desWS As Worksheet
        
    Set srcWS = Sheets("Pivot")
    Set desWS = Sheets("Table1")
    
     
    LastRow = srcWS.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    LastRowDes = desWS.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    lCol = desWS.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    
    For Each header In desWS.Range(desWS.Cells(1, 1), desWS.Cells(1, lCol))
        Set foundHeader = srcWS.Cells(11, 15).Find(header, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
        Set foundHeader9 = srcWS.Cells(11, 17).Find(header, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
        Set foundHeader10 = srcWS.Cells(, 18).Find(header, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
        
        Set foundHeader2 = srcWS.Cells(2, 1).Find(header, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
        Set foundHeader3 = srcWS.Cells(3, 1).Find(header, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
        Set foundHeader4 = srcWS.Cells(4, 1).Find(header, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
        Set foundHeader5 = srcWS.Cells(5, 1).Find(header, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
        Set foundHeader6 = srcWS.Cells(6, 1).Find(header, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
        Set foundHeader7 = srcWS.Cells(7, 1).Find(header, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
        Set foundHeader8 = srcWS.Cells(8, 1).Find(header, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
        
        
        
        If Not foundHeader Is Nothing Then
            srcWS.Range(srcWS.Cells(12, foundHeader.Column), srcWS.Cells(LastRow, foundHeader.Column)).Copy desWS.Cells(LastRowDes + 1, header.Column)
        End If
        
        If Not foundHeader9 Is Nothing Then
            srcWS.Range(srcWS.Cells(12, foundHeader9.Column), srcWS.Cells(LastRow, foundHeader9.Column)).Copy desWS.Cells(LastRowDes + 1, header.Column)
        End If
        
        If Not foundHeader10 Is Nothing Then
            srcWS.Range(srcWS.Cells(12, foundHeader10.Column), srcWS.Cells(LastRow, foundHeader10.Column)).Copy desWS.Cells(LastRowDes + 1, header.Column)
        End If
        
        If Not foundHeader2 Is Nothing Then
            If Not srcWS.Cells(2, 2) = "All" Then
                srcWS.Cells(2, 2).Copy desWS.Cells(LastRowDes + 1, header.Column)
            End If
        End If
        
        If Not foundHeader3 Is Nothing Then
            If Not srcWS.Cells(3, 2) = "All" Then
                srcWS.Cells(3, 2).Copy desWS.Cells(LastRowDes + 1, header.Column)
            End If
        End If
        
        If Not foundHeader4 Is Nothing Then
            If Not srcWS.Cells(4, 2) = "All" Then
                srcWS.Cells(4, 2).Copy desWS.Cells(LastRowDes + 1, header.Column)
            End If
        End If
        
        If Not foundHeader5 Is Nothing Then
            If Not srcWS.Cells(5, 2) = "All" Then
                srcWS.Cells(5, 2).Copy desWS.Cells(LastRowDes + 1, header.Column)
            End If
        End If
        
        If Not foundHeader6 Is Nothing Then
            If Not srcWS.Cells(6, 2) = "All" Then
                srcWS.Cells(6, 2).Copy desWS.Cells(LastRowDes + 1, header.Column)
            End If
        End If
        
        If Not foundHeader7 Is Nothing Then
            If Not srcWS.Cells(7, 2) = "All" Then
                srcWS.Cells(7, 2).Copy desWS.Cells(LastRowDes + 1, header.Column)
            End If
        End If
        
        If Not foundHeader8 Is Nothing Then
            If Not srcWS.Cells(8, 2) = "All" Then
                srcWS.Cells(8, 2).Copy desWS.Cells(LastRowDes + 1, header.Column)
            End If
        End If
        
    Next header
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Is it enough to only check if Column "O" is populated? Or do all four have to be empty?

Comment: Hello...yes, it is okay to only check Column "O".

Comment: If I understand you correctly, your `srcWS.Range(srcWS.Cells(12, foundHeader.Column), srcWS.Cells(LastRow, foundHeader.Column)).Copy` will also copy the blank row (if any) within row 12 to whatever last row number. If you don't want to include the blank row, maybe try `srcWS.Range(srcWS.Cells(12, foundHeader.Column), srcWS.Cells(LastRow, foundHeader.Column)).specialcells(xlconstants).copy` --> this will copy the row from row 12 to whatever last row number which has a value only. The result after it paste into `desWS.Cells(LastRowDes + 1, header.Column)` will be in a consecutive row with value.

Comment: This works, however, I notice that foundheader 2,3,4,5,6,7,8 should also get pasted for all the rows with value (currently just getting pasted once  .